# iOS Open clickable link in PDF file

Tags: swift, pdf

I receive a pdf file from server which has a clickable link in it. I want to open url via browser when tap on this link. 
Pdf file is opened using UIDocumentInteractionController and it doesnot allow me to open that link. Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Check the below URL, it may be help full for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531572/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-does-not-open-other-app-in-ios-11

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only preview PDF means you can go with [`QLPreviewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller), In this you can't do share or print or download like `UIDocumentInteractionController`, you can only view any documents.